# Getting at the data in my json file?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm still trying to wrap my head around json and getting access to the data.

Here's my json format, which I hope is logical for the type of data I'm using...

```
{"round1": [
    {
        "category" : "north",
        "match1": [
            {
                "name": "Team1",
                "score": 90
            },
            {
                "name": "Team2",
                "score": 96
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "category" : "east",
        "match2": [
            {
                "name": "Team3",
                "score": 32
            },
            {
                "name": "Team4",
                "score": 84
            }
        ]
    }
],
    "round2": [
        {
            "category" : "south",
            "match1": [
                {
                    "name": "Team2",
                    "score": 90
                },
                {
                    "name": "Team4",
                    "score": 96
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm trying to get at the data in there using...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //LOAD JSON
    $.getJSON("json.js", function(data) {
        alert(data.round1[i].match1[i]);
    }
}
```

How would I get at the following data:

- category for match2 in round1?
- score for match1 in round2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON is just a JavaScript object. So if your JSON is already an object in JavaScript, you can simply access data like this: `object.round1[1].category`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as in this example

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  //LOAD JSON
  $.each(data,function(i,item){
    console.log(item);
  });
});
```

[Demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wv5A9/)